# how to check mobile have internet or not

Tags: javascript, cordova, internet-connection

I have one mobile. i need test mobile have internet or not. I tried like this

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
alert("selectitem");
}
function onOnline() {
alert("deivce have enternet");
}
```

and we tried other way like this

```
if (navigator.onLine) {
}
```

both methods are not working for me.

We developing Phone-Gap app. after install app will be need to check mobile have Internet or not.

Comment: @Omar if you anything about my problem please help me.give me any idea

Comment: If you are working on a hybrid mobile application then you need to enable Internet access in Cordova configuration files.

Comment: @Gajotres  we developing Phone gap application.We add AndroidManifest.xml like this
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

Comment: Is it Phonegap or Cordova? There's a big difference.

Comment: If you are working with Cordova you can use this plugin to detect internet connection and connection  type: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information

Comment: @Gajotres  PhoneGap application .if you know how to solve my problem Please help me.

Comment: try using window.navigator.onLine instead of navigator.onLine

Comment: As @Gajotres said - you should add the network info plugin. Can you confirm you did that?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check `navigator.connection.type` [as documented here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md).

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var isOffline = navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE;
}
```

Checking that property will get you the network state at the time you check it. You can also use the `online` and `offline` events to detect when the connection status changes.

Make sure you:

1. include the network-information plugin during build
2. include the correct app permissions to access network state
3. don't try to check `navigator.connection.type` until after the `deviceready` event.